# Why PriorityQueue does not have a constructor with Collection and Comparator arguments?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, heap, priority-queue

Creating a `PriorityQueue` from a `Collection` has a time complexity of *O(N)*. 
When creating a `PriorityQueue` with `Comparator`, then `addAll(Collection)` has a time complexity of *O(N log N)*.

How can I take advantage of the fact that the heapify algorithm has a time complexity of *O(n)* when I am using a `Comparator`?

Comment: According to the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue-java.util.Collection-) the time complexity of the PriorityQueue is only O(n) when a SortedSet or PriorityQueue is passed in, otherwise for other collections it is O(nlogn).

Comment: @TravisCook Where does it say that the complexity varies depending on the type of collection?

Comment: @JimMischel Sorry, I referenced the document explaining the differences in the constructors, but forgot to give more detail.  Looking at the implementation (bytecode version: 55), the runtimes appear to vary based on the type of collection passed in.
PriorityQueue(PriorityQueue) - O(1),
PriorityQueue(SortedSet) - O(n),
PriorityQueue(Collection) - O(nlogn)